# python / php - cross-language string compression (uses gzcompress/urlencode/json)

Tags: php, python, base64, gzip

I have a routine in Python 2.6 that stores large amounts of html text in an AWS DynamoDB database, the problem is that these 'blobs' are sucking up a lot of space and compute unites when doing simple retrievals so I'm looking at ways to compress the strings into something much more lightweight.

I've done some simple tests on the following and it works (greatly reduces DynamoDB compute units) but I'm looking for input on whether or not this is the best way to go about it.

The following is the Python 2.6 code I use to generate a plain text gzip compressed version of the json array. The json array contains a few keys each with a big blob of html.

```
import urllib, json
str = urllib.quote(json.dumps({'foo1': 'bar'}).encode('zlib').encode('base64'))
```

Then with php I can run the following to return the string to its natural array:

```
json_decode(gzuncompress(base64_decode(urldecode($str))),1);
```

Does anyone have any tips or is this the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: thx, I'm slowly getting better at posting better questions on SO :)

Comment: Is it necessary to encode the string with Base64? Otherwise, your solution seems to be a good one. If noone comes up with a better idea, answer your own question Q&A-style and rephrase your original question to match.

Comment: The reason for base64 encode is it converts the response from gzip (bytes) into a plain alphanumeric string which can then be stored in database as a plain string. base64 decode then converts the string back into bytes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have data as plain string in database? You could omit base64 encoding and save data to database as binary to slightly improve speed of your code. Anyway the data is gzipped so you are not able to visualize it directly. http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/08/21/dynamodb-announces-binary-data-types/

Answer (score 0):

You could use base64 encoding

Python Code:

```
import base64
print(base64.b64encode(b"Hello World").decode())
```

PHP Code:

```
base64_decode("your base64 encoded text from the python script")
```